# VNC server failed to start

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

My Linux computer shut down due to a power outage. After restarting it, I couldn't reconnect my computer through vncviewer. I logged into my computer and checked the status with

```
sudo systemctl status vncserver@:1.service
```

The error messages can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARF92.png), and some notable ones are below:

```
lambda-quad pkexec[9665]: lulab: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/] [COMMAND=/usr/lib...]
lambda-quad skystemd[1]: vncserver@:1.server: start operation timed out. Terminating.
lambda-quad skystemd[1]: vncserver@:1.server: Failed with result 'timeout'.
lambda-quad skystemd[1]: Failed to start Systemd VNC server startup script for Ubuntu 20.04
```

I tried to restart the vncserver with:

```
sudo systemctl start vncserver@:1.service
```

Then, I got an error message that:

```
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
```

Is anyone able to tell me what's going wrong and what I could do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I've never used tightvnc, but I would assume it has some logs somewhere. Try looking in `/var/log` and see if there's anything of relevance.

Answer (score 1):

you can enter `vncserver` to check the error tips like:

```
[root@www tmp]# vncserver

Warning: www:1 is taken because of /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
Remove this file if there is no X server www:1

Warning: www:5 is taken because of /tmp/.X11-unix/X5
Remove this file if there is no X server www:5
```

Then try:

```
[root@www .vnc]# rm -rf ~/.vnc/www\:1.pid 
[root@www tmp]# rm -rf /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
```

restart the vncserver again:

```
[root@www tmp]# systemctl start vncserver@:1.service
```

Comment: Yeah, that totally doesn't work. `vncserver` gives me specific files I need to remove. Then when I look, those files just don't exist. Like, it says, `Warning: svr:1 is taken because of /tmp/.X1-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server svr:1` and then when I do `sudo rm /tmp/.X1-lock` it says `ls: cannot access '/tmp/.X1-lock': No such file or directory`. So, this "answer" is a real great way to get false information and not get anything at all fixed! Just like literally every other one of the over 200 Stack Exchange answers I've tried in the last 9 hellish days of this!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just command as your real user (not root):

`vncserver`

It's not service, but seems your sudo command complaints about root user as well, if root doesn't have GUI sessions may be a reason.

Edit:

It would be good to check which user it starts with.

This is excerpt from:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Start TigerVNC vncserver at boot
The ubuntu install package also registers a system service, making it easy to define listening vnc servers on startup. Edit the file `/etc/default/vncserver` and add the display number and user to start as:

`VNCSERVERS="1:myusername"`

Then enable the service at boot with:

`sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I killed the dead process (vncserver -kill:1) and restart a new process (vncserver :1), it works! However, when I rebooted the computer, the problem occurred again. Do you know how to fix the auto-start issue? Thank you!

Comment: It would be best to find a reason why the process hangs in the first place. But you could just do a "hammer" solution, and add a job in cron something like `@reboot sleep 15 && vncserver -kill:1 && vncserver:1`. But could you restart PC and upload vncserver log of just what happens after boot? Most files should be in system log and in `$HOME/.vnc/`. Also check update to answer in a minute, and check that